# Should we Recite pratah smaran slokas before or after bathing?

Tags: scripture, puranas, shloka, stotra, puja

There are many pratah smaran stotram and slokas of various gods (Shiva , devi , Ganesh etc) aswell as of holy being (panch devi sapt cheeranjivi etc). We also have slokas such "karagre vaste Lakshmi...". My question is do we chant these the moment we wake up or after bathing ?

Comment: after waking up, before bathing

Comment: These mantras must be chanted immediately after getting up i.e. on the bed itself. There are certain mantras which are required to be chanted as soon as we get up. Bathing not needed for those.